# Does Fiat need dedicated FiCom OBD hardware and software for diagnostics?

Tags: diagnostics, fiat, software, elm-327

I got an ELM 327 with Bluetooth from my brother in law. We have tested it in his Chevrolet Aveo with several apps and it works like a charm.

When I tried it on my Fiat Panda 2012, the apps couldn't connect and some apps notify me that no compatible obd2 protocol is detected.

After some research I found [this](http://www.obdtester.com/ficom) site that says Fiat, amongst others, use something called FicCom. It doesn't clearly state that it should be used with dedicated hardware, only that the FiCom hardware has some extra special features.

A [forum](http://www.digital-kaos.co.uk/forums/showthread.php/299463-FiCOM-Fiat-Alfa-Lancia-diagnostics) I came across, which has no regard for the English language or Internet Internet etiquette, has some posts that states that you do need dedicated hardware for that, though I learned to not always trust a sparsely moderated forum as is.

> Am I out of luck to try and communicate with my Panda through the generic ELM 327 interface, or do I just need special software that can understand the FiCom language of Fiat?

Comment: Do you have the header address and PIDs to request to get DTCs from all control modules (engine, ABS, airbag etc.)?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try [Multi ECU Scan](http://www.multiecuscan.net/). It's a free/non-free software suite that works with most, if not all, FIAT's. Most of the diagnostic tools can be accessed for free. Other tools require a licence. The licence is not that expensive so it could be worth the investment. In no way is this my software nor my company. I know about the software because I used it to diagnose my 2002 Panda.

The Panda will most likely have [OBD connectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On-board_diagnostics):

[image]

so you'll need the appropriate cable and adaptor. For completeness sake, [here is a link with pictures showing where to find the connector](http://www.outilsobdfacile.com/location-plug-connector-obd/Fiat-Panda-2).

Comment: Can you elaborate more on this scanner?

Comment: @cloudnyn3 Sure. What would you like to know?

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this software a try this afternoon. I've read that it fully supports the Bluetooth ELM 327 as well.